# Getting LiveStreamManager error -3 in DJI Mobile SDK when trying to stream to custom RTMP?

Tags: java, android, rtmp, dji-sdk

I'm trying to implement a app that sends live video from drone to my custom rtmp server. When I use de LiveStreamManager from DJI Mobile SDK it gives me error code -3, and the stream do not start. How can I use this API?

My app registers successfully, I can setup missions, and get telemetry from drone. But when I try to use the LiveStreamManeger it won't work no matter what. Even by implementing exactly the way it is implemented in [Sample Code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/tree/master/Sample%20Code), it does not work. Documentation in DJI API reference seems to be missing a few methods as well.

Here is my implementation

```java
    private void setupLiveStream() {
        DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().registerListener(listener);
        initListener();
        DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().setAudioStreamingEnabled(false);
        DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().setVideoSource(LiveStreamManager.LiveStreamVideoSource.Primary);
        liveURL = "rtmp://mycustomrtmp.com/drone/live_testDJI";
    }

    private void initListener() {
        listener = new LiveStreamManager.OnLiveChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(int i) {
                setResultToToast("status changed : " + i);
            }
        };
    }
    private void StartStreaming(){
        if (!isLiveStreamManagerOn()) {
            return;
        }
        if (DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().isStreaming()) {
            setResultToToast("already started the Stream!");
            return;
        }
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().setLiveUrl(liveURL);// + vehicleID);
                int result = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().startStream();
                DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().setStartTime();
                setResultToToast("LiveStream Start: " + result +
                        "\n isVideoStreamSpeedConfigurable:" + DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().isVideoStreamSpeedConfigurable() +
                        "\n isLiveAudioEnabled:" + DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager().isLiveAudioEnabled());
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

I always get a return code -3. When I use the sample code I can get it to work. The only diference is then I call the function isVideoStreamSpeedConfigurable(), it returns true on my code, and false on sample code. But I did not see where I can set this thing to false. How should I implement LiveStreamingManager?

Comment: For this while, I'm using de sample code and converting it to my app. Process is slow since I have do delete classes one by one and check how it is going to affect the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I've managed to solve the issue. Apparently, to be able to use the LiveStreamManager you must first call the function VideoFeeder.getPrimaryVideoFeed() somewhere in your code or it will give error code -3.

Using the Sample Code there is a class in internal.utils.VideoFeedView that can be used to this purpose

I have first declared a private property VideoFeedView.

Then on my class constructor I call the initUI function.

```java
private VideoFeedView primaryVideoFeed;

private void initUI() {
   primaryVideoFeed.registerLiveVideo(VideoFeeder.getInstance().getPrimaryVideoFeed(),true);
   startStreaming();

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but your solution is not working for me. Where did you find this out, maybe there are more solutions for me there.

Comment: Actually I've found with trial and error. There is not much support with DJI MSDK anywhere, and DJI itself don't seem to be interested either. We developers end up having to dig these workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I just was lucky, but for me, the following code solved my problem. I didn't have any need for anything more, like VideoFeedView. What is the reason for using that?
I running on a mavic 2 pro and streaming 30fps 720p to youtube.

```
    private LiveStreamManager l;
    public int live_streaming_start(String live_url){
      Log.d("MavicMax", "LiveStream:live_streaming_start:" + live_url);
      l = DJISDKManager.getInstance().getLiveStreamManager();
      l.registerListener((x)->{Log.d("MavicMax", "LiveStream callback:" + x);});
      l.setVideoSource(LiveStreamManager.LiveStreamVideoSource.Primary);
      l.setVideoEncodingEnabled(true);
      l.setLiveUrl(live_url);
      int r = 0;
      r = l.startStream();
      return r;
}
```

Comment: Are you showing the live video to the user? like using uxsdk and fpvwidget?

Comment: Yes I do, uxsdk, doesn't it works without that you mean?